# How to configure Azure AD Oauth2 to return all user groups on login

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have an AD registered application which has an integration with Azure AD for SSO. It uses the Oauth2 strategy, by using the `omniauth-azure-activedirectory-v2` gem.

I want to map a users security groups to my applications authorization model and for this I need the names of the security groups.

I want to reliably get a users security groups and the group names on login and I'm not able to. I get them sometimes correctly, sometimes in a uuid format and sometimes not at all.

I have an optional [group claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims) set up for my application in `Token Configuration` and configured to return `sam_account_name` for all attached groups.

This seems to work fine for some clients, the groups are returned as for example "Admin_APP", but for others I seem to have the following issues:

- A Users groups are returned but only as a ID(`c5bb3738-59f1-4718-b34c-2dfac761e023`), even tough I requested the name.
- A User has "readable groups" but not all assigned in AD, some are missing.

Is this a configuration on my application side or should the organization adding my application to their AD configure their groups or my application? Or should I not rely on the token cliam at all and fetch the groups using the GraphQL API Azure offers?

I noticed when adding the application myself I need to give permissions for my user.profile but it doesn't show allowable permissions for groups. Also in the Enterprise application tab for the organization under `permissions` I can't seem to find the group claim I added. Only `openid`, `profile` and `email`.

Comment: The more robust strategy for getting group memberships is to query them through MS Graph API. For example if a user has too many groups, they won't fit in the token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I configured the **Optional claims** in Azure AD Application:

[image]

I generated the **access token** via Postman by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:user.read openid
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:redirectUri
code:code
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, I got the **`Group IDs`** instead of Group Name like below:

[image]

**Note** that: If you are configuring `sAMAccountName`  as the claim value in the token, then it only returns the Group which is synced from on-premises AD. By default, Group **`ObjectID`** is returned in the group claim value.

> **By default**, groups emitted in a token is limited to 150 for SAML
> assertions and 200 for JWT.

I agree with ***junnas***, you can make use of Graph API to get the user groups like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/memberOf
```

[image]

To get the only list of security groups user belongs to, you can make use of below query:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/memberOf?Filter("mailEnabled eq false and securityEnabled eq true")
```

[image]

**References:**

[List a user's direct memberships - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[How to get groups to appear as claims in the access_token by AmanpreetSingh-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/719457/how-to-get-groups-to-appear-as-claims-in-the-acces)